Different string lifetimes and drop
Consider this function that returns the longest string slice from two slices with equal lifetimes.
fn get_longest<'a>(s1: &'a str, s2: &'a str) -> &'a str {
    if s1.len() > s2.len() {
        s1
    } else {
        s2
    }
}

Now consider this test function that should fail because the arguments have different lifetimes.
#[test]
fn with_different_lifetimes() {
    let s1 = "very long string";
    let s2 = "tiny".to_string();
    let should_be_s1 = get_longest(s1, &s2);
    drop(s2);
    assert_eq!(should_be_s1, "very long string");
}

This is the error that the test function correctly produces.
error[E0505]: cannot move out of `s2` because it is borrowed
let s2 = "tiny".to_string();
    -- binding `s2` declared here
let should_be_s1 = get_longest(s1, &s2);
                                   --- borrow of `s2` occurs here
drop(s2);
     ^^ move out of `s2` occurs here
assert_eq!(should_be_s1, "very long string");
-------------------------------------------- borrow later used here

help: consider cloning the value if the performance cost is acceptable

let should_be_s1 = get_longest(s1, &s2);
let should_be_s1 = get_longest(s1, s2.clone());

Now let's say I don't have access to the test function so I cannot change it like the compiler suggests, so to make it pass I changed the return type of get_longest to String.
fn get_longest(s1: &str, s2: &str) -> String {
    if s1.len() > s2.len() {
        s1.to_owned()
    } else {
        s2.to_owned()
    }
}

How can I change the original function get_longest so that the test function with_different_lifetimes passes and it will still return a reference to a string slice instead of a new String?
In other words, this test function that compares the references should also pass.
#[test]
fn equal_reference() {
    let s1 = "tiny";
    let s2 = "very long string".to_string();
    let should_be_ref_s2 = get_longest(s1, &s2);
    assert_eq!(should_be_ref_s2, &s2);
}

Is this possible?

This test asserts equality of contents, not identity of references.

I don't see how returning &str would ever work. If you assume the second parameter cannot be preserved, you could return Cow<str> bound to the first parameter's lifetime.

@ChayimFriedman You mean equal_reference? Yes, I agree, but my question still stands, how can I make it compile?

I'm not sure if I completely understand. You want to return a ref which possibly is a ref to the s2, drop the origin value s2, and make the possible ref to a drooped value safely stay alive without cloning?

The only issue with your second test is that you can't compare String and &String. The comparison operators are not often implemented between owned types and references since the operators take their operands by reference already. However, there's no harm in doing so.
You can't make impl PartialEq<&String> for String, but you can make a wrapper type that is comparable to both &str and &String. This will make both tests compile and pass.
#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct StringCmp(pub String);

impl PartialEq<&String> for StringCmp {
    fn eq(&self, other: &&String) -> bool {
        self.0.eq(*other)
    }
}

impl PartialEq<&str> for StringCmp {
    fn eq(&self, other: &&str) -> bool {
        self.0.eq(*other)
    }
}

pub fn get_longest(s1: &str, s2: &str) -> StringCmp {
    if s1.len() > s2.len() {
        StringCmp(s1.to_owned())
    } else {
        StringCmp(s2.to_owned())
    }
}

Playground

AFAICS this answer is missing the point of the question: OP is asking if there is a way to make the -> &'a str-version (avoiding the -> String) work in both cases (drop(s2)). The answer is no, because should_be_s1 is a 'a-borrow into either s1 or s2, where 'a is the "longest" common denominator of the input lifetimes (due to covariance). There is no way to shorten 'a after the fact (the drop(s2) invalidates that borrow, in case should_be_s1 turns out to be &'a s2 at runtime).

This doesn't "return a reference to a string slice instead of a new String" It returns new strings!
